# Issues with starting Postgres and its /tmp/ files

Tags: sql, database, macos, postgresql, unix

I have installed and uninstalled Postgres a bunch of times now and this is where I'm at:

when I run `psql postgres` I get this error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

when I run this command:

`pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start && brew services start postgresql`

I get this error:

```
waiting for server to start....2018-01-21 17:02:39.204 PST [10947] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2018-01-21 17:02:39.205 PST [10947] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "fe80::1%lo0", port 5432
2018-01-21 17:02:39.205 PST [10947] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2018-01-21 17:02:39.205 PST [10947] LOG:  could not bind Unix address "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432": Address already in use
2018-01-21 17:02:39.205 PST [10947] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, remove socket file "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" and retry.
2018-01-21 17:02:39.205 PST [10947] WARNING:  could not create Unix-domain socket in directory "/tmp"
2018-01-21 17:02:39.205 PST [10947] FATAL:  could not create any Unix-domain sockets
2018-01-21 17:02:39.205 PST [10947] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

my `/tmp` directory does not have a `.s.PGSQL.5432` file, and my `sudo lsof -i tcp:5432` displays nothing, indicating that nothing is running on that port

..

**UPDATE (workaround)**

I downloaded the Postgress.app, changed the port I wanted to use to 5435 and Postgres seems to be working fine now, but it would be nice to know how to fix this error

Answer (score 1):

I have a little confuse about your command

`pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start && brew services start postgresql`

Because the command `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start` is for start database daemon and the command `brew services start postgresql` is do the same thing.

That means you try to start database two times and of course the second one can not start.

Could you try to run one command only?